# MongoDB aggregation split string with a regex

Tags: mongodb

I want to split a string given a regex within a MongoDB aggregation

The documentation says :

> The $split operator returns an array. The  and
>  inputs must both be strings. Otherwise, the operation
> fails with an error.

Do you know to perfom the same thing with a regex ?

I would like to ideally keep the delimiter with the next split

Here is an example of data :

```
input = "[part1]
         aaaa
         [part2]
         bbbb
         [part3]
         cccc"

regex = r"(?:^|\n)\[part\d+\]"

output = ["[part1]
         aaaa",
         "[part2]
         bbbb",
         "[part3]
         cccc"]
```

Comment: It is possible I think. Let me know if you are still looking for an answer.

Comment: Found a solution (maybe not the best) : I used $RegexFindAll to retrieve the idx of the brackets as an array, $slice to create another array without the first element, $zip to zip the idx array with the offset idx array, $unwind to get start and end position of each part, and then $substrCP to get get what I want from my string input...

Comment: Exact what I was about to suggest. Glad you found a solution :)